# Least error prone way to add columns to an R data.frame through functions

Tags: r, dataframe

The case I have is I want to "tack on" a bunch of columns to an existing data.frame, where each column is a function that does math on other columns.  My goals are:

1. I want to specify the functions once
2. I don't want to worry about having to pass arguments in the right order and/or match them by name
3. I want to specify the order in which to apply the functions once
4. I want the new column names to be the function names

Ideally I want something like:

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))
y <- function (x) a + b
z <- function (x) b * y
df2 <- lapply (list (y, z), df)
```

where df2 is a data.frame with 4 columns: a, b, y and z.  I think this achieves the goals.

The closest I've gotten to this is the following:

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))
y <- function (x) x$a + x$b
z <- function (x) x$b * x$y
funs <- list (
  y = y,
  z = z
)
df2 <- df
df2$y <- funs$y(df2)
df2$z <- funs$z(df2)
```

This achieves goals 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does this work for you? `for (i in 1:length(funs)) {df[, names(funs)[i]] <- funs[[i]](df)}`

Comment: Yes @Gopala that seems to work.  Couple of follow up questions: (1) is there any benefit to using your solution with an lapply instead of a for loop?, and (2) is there any way to get around the need to specify y = y in the list definition (i.e. it just be funs <- list (y, z) with some argument saying to infer the names as is?)

Comment: You could say `funs <- list(y = function(x) x$a + x$b, z = ....)`. Not sure about `apply` family. There must be a way to do a `global` assignment in the function. A loop is not always a bad thing though. Very clear and simple in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe the thing you want. After defining the function dfapply, it can be used very similar to your original intention without too much things like x$a etc, except to use expression instead of function.

```
dfapply <- function(exprs, df){
    for (expr in exprs) {
        df <- within(df, eval(expr))
    }
    df
}

df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))
expr1 <- expression(y <- a + b)
expr2 <- expression(z <- b * y)
df2 <- dfapply(c(expr1, expr2), df)
```